# Why my else condition is beeing executed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, arraylist

I am new to Javascript and I was making a little chat bot, nothing to fancy, but I am stuck in a problem where if I input something to it that matches a value inside an array it will execute the if and the else condition.

```js
function readInput(){
var words = ["hello", "hi", "holis", "holus"];
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value.toLowerCase();
console.log(" Users says: " + userInput);

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if(userInput == words[i]){
      console.log("bot says: " + "hi!");

    }else {
      console.log("bot says " + "i dont understand");
    }
  }
  //clean  user input
  var clearInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value="";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" value="">

    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="readInput()">Say</button>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: because you are checking each index and if that index does not match than it goes to the else. You are expecting it to only go into it when all of them do not match, so you need to change your logic.

Comment: Because you keep checking the array before and/or after you have a match. You need to check *all* the words and see if *any* match and that's your condition, not check *each one* as your condition. There are many ways to do that.

Comment: Use `if (words.includes(userInput))`

Comment: that totally fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify your for statement.

Define a variable to check if your script know the word. In the for statement, if the input word is in the `words`, then set the variable true then break. Finally if the check variable is false, than say I don't understand:

```
var check = false
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (userInput == words[i]) {
        console.log("bot says: " + "hi!");
        check = true;
        break
    }
}
if (!check) {
    console.log("bot says " + "i dont understand");
}
```